# MSDeploy - Allow Parameter to be optional / empty in parameters.xml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, teamcity, msdeploy, web-config

I am using [msdeploy](/questions/tagged/msdeploy) to deploy a [asp.net-mvc](/questions/tagged/asp.net-mvc) web application via [[image]teamcity](/questions/tagged/teamcity).

I am using a [paramaters.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398068(v=vs.110).aspx) file to manipulate my application's [web.config](/questions/tagged/web.config), specifically the application [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx) section.

I have some Settings where it is only valid to have a value for a specific environment and the rest of the time the value should be blank (ie, Property should only have a value on Production).  However, MSDeploy gives me this Exception when I do **not** specify a value:

```
 Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentException: 
   The 'facebookUserToken' argument cannot be null or empty.
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterValidation.Validate(String parameterName, String parameterValue)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameter.set_Value(String value)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.LoadFromFile(XPathNavigator nav, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.Load(Stream stream, String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentSyncParameterCollection.Load(String fileName, Boolean ignoreExtraSetParameters)
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.HandleSetParameters(DeploymentObject sourceObject, Random random)
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.ExecuteWorker()
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Execute()
   at MSDeploy.MSDeploy.Main(String[] unusedArgs)
```

**How can I configure MSDeploy to allow a *parameter* to have an empty value?**

web.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
    <SO.Example>
        <setting name="FacebookUserToken" serializeAs="String">
           <value></value>
        </setting>
    </SO.Example>
</applicationSettings>
```

parameters.config:

```
   <parameter name="facebookUserToken" description="" defaultValue="">   
      <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config"
      match="XPath removed for readability">
       </parameterEntry>
   </parameter>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I ran across this issue a while back and found the solution at [Richard Szalay's blog](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2012/09/13/declaring-optional-msdeploy-parameters-using-the-web-publishing-pipeline/).  You need to add the *parameterValidation* to your *parameter* declaration:

```
<parameters> 
   <parameter name="ReplaceVariable"
          description="Sample variable that allows empty values" defaultValue="">
     <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />
     <parameterEntry type="TextFile" scope="Web\.config$" match="TextToReplace" /> 
   </parameter> 
</parameters>
```

So for your specific case:

```
  <parameter name="facebookUserToken" description="" defaultValue="">   
      <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty"/>
      <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config"
      match="XPath removed for readability">
       </parameterEntry>
   </parameter>
```

Comment: I just want point out that this [IIS.net page](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/windows-web-application-gallery/reference-for-the-web-application-package) does not work with MsBuild 14. `parameterValidation` should have `kind` attribute instead of `type` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

I think you're looking for `<parameterValidation />`.

In your parameters.config:

```
<parameter name="facebookUserToken" description="" defaultValue=""> 
    <parameterValidation kind="AllowEmpty" />  
    <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="Web.config"
       match="XPath removed for readability">
    </parameterEntry>
</parameter>
```